# Domain controller in Azure replacement

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

For my graduate project i dove into Microsoft Azure and i had no clue how it worked. Now, a few months later, i need to make some decisions.

For this project I am planning to migrate clients of an MSP to Azure. A typical client currently has 1 DC and 1 RDS in the on-premise setup. Now to host these servers in Azure it is possible to host the DC as a VM (like in a traditional setup) but I can also setup AAD, AADDS, Azure DNS for the client instead of the DC as a VM. So there is only 1 VM needed (for the RDS).

What is recommended for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD Domain Services is a managed domain. You don't need to provision, configure, or otherwise manage domain controllers for this domain. These management activities are provided as a service by Microsoft. So yes, if you are planning to move to [cloud-only Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#azure-ad-ds-for-cloud-only-organizations), then you do not need DC/VM. You can also use, [ADDS for hybrid infrastructure.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#azure-ad-ds-for-hybrid-organizations)

Comment: Great answer, thanks in advance. There is not much information on the internet.

What about the costs? Are those services to host a Azure Domain more or less expensive than a DC/VM?

Comment: The costs depend on the load we are expecting to handle. For e.g. ADDS Central US rates range from  $0.15/hour/set to $1.60/hour/set depending on your requirement. (It comes with 2 domain controllers for High Availability). Please refer to the below links for addidtional information. :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory-ds/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/

Most of this information can be obtained from Microsoft Documentation. However, feel free to let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, so do you recommend me to setup RDS hosts in Azure as a VM and setup the DC not as a VM but with Azure services?

Comment: I’am also truggling with Azure VM types, like what Azure VM serie is recommended for a RDS host? Can you help me with this question?

Comment: @RickJanssen Yes, you can set up the RDS host as VM and Azure AD and ADDS in place of DC.  Here is the virtual machine sizing guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/virtual-machine-recs

Comment: Thanks, is there a guidance for DC as a VM in Azure? Like which type is best practice?

Comment: Sure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/virtual-dc/virtualized-domain-controllers-hyper-v      https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/888794/things-to-consider-when-you-host-active-directory-domain-controllers-i

Comment: The best approach would be to move to AAD and AADS unless you want to keep things On-Prem.